# Merchandise has little in the way of description

Tags: discussion, shop, merchandise

I just looked at some of the SO merchandise, and was surprised by how little useful information was available.

For example, the [StackOverflow Laptop Bag](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/laptop-bag) doesn't even contain size information.  Without that, how am I to know if my laptop will fit inside it?  That's kind of important to know if I'm thinking of buying one.  (Especially if I have a laptop with a screen larger than 15 inches.  That seems to be the point where a good bag goes from "easy to find" to "hard to find.")

That's just one example.  Could someone look over the shop pages and add some stats and other useful information to them?

Comment: On the pens it says `Stack Exchange Blue ink` - why is "blue" capitalized? :O

Comment: @animuson It's the official blue colour used by Stack Exchange, of course.